# How to configure URL in Oracle Service Bus 12C

Tags: osb

How can I configure URL's using Oracle Service Bus 12C. Suppose I have a url `http://whatever.com/rest/services` and I need this to go through OSB. I went through the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to call a service on that URL or simply trying to use some http methods on it (GET/POST). 
Simply create a "business service" (which is a component in the OSB) and add your URL in the "endpoint URI" field.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it doing double click in your proxy and select the Transport tab:

[image]

In this case the final URL is: http:///elasticsearch-sb/ProxyService